# Spring Cloud config throws NPE empty for array in the file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

We used Spring Cloud Config version 2.1 and it worked.
We updated to Spring Cloud Config 2.2, and now it does not work.
More details are
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1599
I reported the issue to accelerate the process as well, or maybe it is not an issue. I do not know, so I am asking you to help.

Our config file: **python-service.yml**

```
resources:
  - resource1
  - resource2

newResources: []
```

As I learned, Spring Cloud config client makes requests to fetch configuration, and it passes header

`Accept: application/vnd.spring-cloud.config-server.v2+json`.
In Spring Cloud config v 2.1

### Note, Spring Cloud version 2.1 does not send such header; instead, it sends `Accept: application/json`

```
HTTP http://localhost:8888/python-service/dev
Accept: application/vnd.spring-cloud.config-server.v2+json
```

Returns

```
{
    "name": "python-service",
    "profiles": [
        "dev"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "file:/configuration/python-service.yml",
            "source": {
                "resources[0]": "resource1",
                "resources[1]": "resource2",
                "newResources": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, it Spring Cloud Config v 2.2, it fails

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-24T08:38:19.803+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Could not construct context for config=python-service profile=dev label=null includeOrigin=true; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "path": "/python-service/dev"
}
```

## The funny thing is that there is no exception log output in config-service logs!

If I remove the accept header, I will get (**version 2.2**)

```
{
    "name": "python-service",
    "profiles": [
        "dev"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "file:/configuration/python-service.yml",
            "source": {
                "resources[0]": "resource1",
                "resources[1]": "resource2",
                "newResources": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here, why `"newResources": ""` became an empty String, if it is expected to be an empty array - another question.

### To sum up

- 1) How to use empty array in Spring Cloud config.
- 2) Why there is no log message about the NPE in Spring config-service logs.
- 3) Without the accept header, why `"newResources": ""` became an empty String, if I expected an empty array.

As for now, I can remove empty array from my config, but it is very scary because our config is used in many services! This breaks backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, it is a bug in Spring Boot.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1572#issuecomment-620496235

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20506

Possible options:

- 1) Wait until it is fixed and update libraries.
- 2) What we did. We replaced empty array with empty element.

```
newResources:
anotherField: value
```

alternatively, use `null`. However, make sure, your code can handle it. Also, emptyArray can be treated as an `emptyString`. I found this out in debugger.